# How to write a python function that will take a dataframe as input, normalize its columns with numeric data type and return the result

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first question here, so I apologize in advance.

I want to write a function that takes dataframe name as argument and applies MinMaxScaler() on the dataframe columns that have numeric data type (int64). I looked it up in the internet and wrote the following code, which gave me the error, 'type' object is not iterable'

```
def standard(df):
        "Takes a dataframe and returns the dataframe with standardized numerical columns" 
        from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
        scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        int_column = []
        for column in pd.DataFrame:
            if 'int' in str(dtype(column)):
                int_column.append(column)
                df[int_column] = scaler.fit_transform(df[int_column])
                return (df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']

numeric_df = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
```

or with new version of pandas

```
numeric_df = df.select_dtypes('number')
```

So for your case

```
def standard(df):
    "Takes a dataframe and returns the dataframe with standardized numerical columns"
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    int_columns = df.select_dtypes('number').columns
    df[int_columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df[int_columns])
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution that you have provided after 'So for your case' worked. I have two follow up questions:
1) Does the word 'number' in the code line include all numeric data types by default (coz we are not defining it)?
`int_columns = df.select_dtypes('number').columns`
2) I tried replacing the word 'number' by int64 to apply scaler to only the column having int64 type (there are other columns that are numeric but are uint8 type (one hot encoded columns), however, it gave the following error when the dataframe was passed as argument:
ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required

Comment: can you try the first approach, where the dtypes are added into the list.

Comment: So, I tried the following code, but it did not scale any column, neither int64, nor any other dtype (the columns I want this function to scale are int64, while other one hot encoded columns are dtype uint8.

`def standard(df):
    "Takes a dataframe and returns the dataframe with standardized numerical columns"
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    numerics = ['int64']
    numeric_df = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
    df[numeric_df] = scaler.fit_transform(df[numeric_df])
    return df`

Comment: I guess you need to use `scaler.fit_transform(numeric_df)`